# Same code works in main() but not in other function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

How can I be, that some code works in the main-function but crashes with a segmentation fault when moved in a function? What's the difference?

This Works:

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int
main() {


    cap_t caps;
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    cap_flag_value_t * val;
    cap_get_flag(caps, CAP_FOWNER, CAP_EFFECTIVE, val);
    cap_free(caps);


    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void
my_get_cap() { 
    cap_t caps;
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    cap_flag_value_t * val;
    cap_get_flag(caps, CAP_FOWNER, CAP_EFFECTIVE, val);
    cap_free(caps);
}

int
main() {
    my_get_cap();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always use `gcc -Wall -Werror`. It would stop you from passing `val` uninitialized to `get_get_flag()`.

Comment: Not exactly causing your trouble, but empty parameter lists for your functions have been a bit outdated since the late eighties of the previous century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized the `cap_flag_value_t * val;` - the call to `cap_get_flag` writes to it and then it may/may not crash depending on the memory location that was written. Change those lines to:

```
cap_flag_value_t val;
cap_get_flag(caps, CAP_FOWNER, CAP_EFFECTIVE, &val);
```